# i want to remove ViewState entry from page without using MVC pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to remove viewstate from page completely without using MVC pattern.

I am using c# 4.0

Thanks in advance. .

Comment: Do you understand what the ViewState is?

Comment: The MVC pattern has nothing to do with ViewState.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't utilise ViewState if you don't use Web Controls, so it is one way of eliminating ViewState. It does mean rewriting your Web Forms app though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store ViewState data in Session: [SessionPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx). That way it won't be sent along with the html.

Answer (score 1):

In the page directive of an ASP.NET page you can disable view state:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="False" ... %>
```